# Is it legal to call a non-static member function of a stateless class on a nullptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, member-functions

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    struct EmptyStruct{
        void nonstatic_mf() const { std::cout <<"EmptyStruct\n"; }
    };


    EmptyStruct *esptr = nullptr;
    esptr->nonstatic_mf(); 
}
```

Is this a legal C++ (it does seem to work in gcc and clang)?

Comment: More interesting question is for static methods :-)

Comment: Adding in code like `if (this != nullptr) ...` don't end well either, because for optimized code the compiler knows that `this` can never be nullptr, so the code is as-if `if (true) ...`.  Undefined behavior:  bad.  Turn on all compiler warnings is one way to have a fighting chance against undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jarod42 do you want me to ask it?

Comment: because simply answering [`[expr.post]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.ref-2.sentence-3) isn't that fun...

Comment: @YSC you have actually answered my question! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Adrian tip: if you're looking for an authoritative answer, tag your question with language-lawyer. We'll know what you're searching for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though the struct is empty, it has a non zero size. There must be some memory that act as a storage for it.

No. This is always UB. Make it static if you don't need the instance. Static functions are still callable using the dot `.` syntax.

Why? Because you cannot dereference a null pointer. Calling a member function  equivalent to this:

```
 EmptyStruct *esptr = nullptr;
 (*esptr).nonstatic_mf();
```

As you can see, the null pointer is deferenced, which is UB.

What does the standard says about this? From [[class.mfct.non-static]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non-static#2):

> If a non-static member function of a class X is called for an object that is not of type X, or of a type derived from X, the behavior is undefined.

A null pointer don't point to a valid instance of `EmptyStruct`. This alone is enough to make the behaviour undefined

And from [[expr.ref]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#2):

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall be a glvalue.
>   For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall be a prvalue having pointer type.
>   The expression `E1->E2` is converted to the equivalent form `(*(E1)).E2`; the remainder of [[expr.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#expr.ref) will address only the first option (dot).

So `esptr->nonstatic_mf()` is effectively equivalent to `(*esptr).nonstatic_mf()`, and derefencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour.

So there's two way in which this code is undefined.

Comment: I guess the ``more or less" here is the crucial part. I would naively say that the argument of a member function is a pointer (no need to dereference anything), but I don't now what standard says about it, so I'm asking.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm marking this as the answer. I was just thinking that perhaps member functions are sort of called by pointer (rather than reference) and built-in arrow is more fundamental than dot (even though dot cannot be overloaded). But it's the other way around.

Comment: @Adrian yes. `this` should have been a reference from the start since it cannot in any well formed way be null. Compilers will even remove checks such as `if (this == nullptr)` when optimisations are enabled.